# Nonprinting Characters no longer appear

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I can't figure out how long this has been going on, but it finally started to drive me crazy: in Libre Office writer, absolutely nothing changes when I toggle the "Nonprinting Characters" button. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> toggles the button on my toolbar, but also does not reveal any nonprinting characters.

How do I start fixing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Found at http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/1697 )

Check your settings at:

Tools > Options... > LibreOffice Writer > Formatting Aids "Display of"

Check the box for "Paragraph Ends" or whichever non-printing character you want to view or hide by toggling. If all the boxes are unticked, you'd not see any non-printing character (which may explain why nothing changes when you click the button or use `ctrl+F10`).

Comment: By default there are not many checkboxes enabled which I think is unfortunate as it makes you wonder if it is working at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Draw the only way I managed -- was to copy the 'offending' text out of Draw's text box, paste it into a blank Writer page, do what I had to do while I could see the formatting codes, then paste it back into Draw.